# MYSQL How to Concat one column with count of another column as a output from DB

Tags: mysql, sql, count, concatenation

I have a Mysql DB and I need to get the show output to the front end. Instead of having logic to iterate in Java code, I would like to get as a custom column from the query output.

```
 
Table: EmpTable
----------------------------------
EmpId     |    DaysCameToOffice
----------------------------------
101       |    Monday
101       |    Tuesday
102       |    Monday
103       |    Monday
102       |    Wednesday
102       |    Thursday
--------------------------------
```

```
 
Desired output (as in Query result)

---------------------------------------------------------
EmpId        |  displayEmp
--------------------------------------------------------
101          |  101 (2 records)
102          |  102 (3 records)
103          |  102 (1 records)
---------------------------------------------------------
```

TRIED queries

```
 
SELECT  m.EmpId as EmpId,
        CONCAT(m.EmpId, " (", COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT(c.DaysCameToOffice) from EmpTable c, " records)") as displayEmp
  FROM EmpTable m
```

Gave me:- Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax

Kindly help me

Comment: Why do this logic during the DB retrieval and not in Java? You can change your query to use a `GROUP BY Empid` and return the columns: `EmpId, COUNT(*)` which Java can easily construct that string for you.

Comment: @Antony: That was my last option - if SQL does this functionality, it would be easier from performance point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count()` works on an expression, not on a query, so you do need to complicate this that much:

```
select empid, concat(empid, ' (', count(distinct DaysCameToOffice),' records)') as displayEmp
from EmpTable
group by empid
```

However, I would run the query without the concatenation, just the count and do this concatenation in the application presenting the results.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Also, thanks for updating me on the count() function :).

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this answer was useful to you, then pls mark it as accepted to let other viewers know that the question has been resolved.